# Why does this code generate a NotSupportedException?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, notsupportedexception

Why does this throw **System.NotSupportedException**?

```
string foo(string f) { return f; }
string bar = "";
var item = (from f in myEntities.Beer
            where f.BeerName == foo(bar)
            select f).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit:** Here's an [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738609.aspx) that (kind of) explains things...

> Any method calls in a LINQ to Entities
> query that are not explicitly mapped
> to a canonical function will result in
> a runtime NotSupportedException
> exception being thrown. For a list of
> CLR methods that are mapped to
> canonical functions, see CLR Method to
> Canonical Function Mapping.

See also http://mosesofegypt.net/post/LINQ-to-Entities-what-is-not-supported.aspx

Comment: This is why I don't like confusing `var`. :-/

Comment: @Nayan: It would show exactly the same behaviour with an explicitly typed local variable.

Comment: Yeah Jon, but it would be readable otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, the code blows up because it doesn't know what to do with the call to `foo()`. The query is built up as an *expression tree* which is then converted to SQL.

The expression tree translator knows about various things - such as string equality, and various other methods (e.g. `string.StartsWith`) but it *doesn't* know what your `foo` method does - `foo()` is a black box as far as it's concerned. It therefore can't translate it into SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The second version will fail as soon as you try to iterate over it. You can't use a locally defined method in an `IQueryable<>` `where` clause (of course, you can, but it will fail when the LINQ provider tries to translate it into SQL).

Answer (score 1):

Because in the 2nd query no actual query is executed.  Try adding `ToList()` where `SingleOrDefault()` is.

It's probably because the SQL-generation functionality isn't able to determine what to do with your `foo()` function, so can't generate output for it.